# Unable to Add NuGet Packages to References in Monodevelop 5

Tags: .net, ubuntu, xamarin, nuget, monodevelop

I recently got Monodevelop 5 up and running from the ermshiperete repository and got NuGet working only after changing the source URL for the gallery to point to a "go link" that uses API version 1.

After installing the latest versions of 'Entity Framework' and 'Microsoft ASP.NET MVC', I see they were added to my packages, which is cool and all, but I need them added to my references for things to work right? Well, I cannot add them to my project's references. When I 'edit references' it does not display them, it only displays packages that I believe already come with the mono installation. I cannot add Entity Framework or Microsoft ASP.NET MVC.

How can I add packages I install to my references?

Can provide screen shots to explain better, perhaps.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are links to screenshots

[References From Packages](http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-07212014-084323pm.php)

[Some of the packages](http://en.zimagez.com/full/17a74ee2cca9894e817defaa1cf6b7545be4776dbb4b30aa6924c0fb25bf0a9d0faaaa7fd1a682526812ebf8842dd7f6826aae929e1ab7a4.php)

Also some background here is that I am new to .NET development, and have been working on this project in VS on a VM, but I would rather just use my normal OS.

Answer (score 3):

So I am assuming you used the **Add Packages** dialog in MonoDevelop 5 to add the NuGet packages to your project and that worked. So you see a packages.config file in your project and the packages inside a **Packages** folder in the Solution window.

Now the assembly references, if there are any defined in the NuGet package, are automatically added to your project when you add the NuGet package. You should be able to see them inside  **References/From Packages** in the Solution window. The screenshot below shows ASP.NET MVC NuGet package and the Entity Framework NuGet package installed.

[image: Packages and references from packages in the Solution window]

So you should not need to use the Edit References dialog for assembly references that are included in the NuGet package but only for other references from the GAC or to reference another project. When you open the Edit References dialog the assembly references from the NuGet package are shown on the right hand side of that dialog in the **Selected References** section.

Comment: haha, thanks for the answer you are very on top of how your add-in is being used. I am not getting dlls in my references, just the names of the packages, hopefully if I figure that issue out it will solve this problem as well...?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If the references are added to the project file (.csproj) then they should appear in the Solution window under the References/From Packages. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I updated the post with links to screenshots. I managed after a lot of updating of packages and flailing around to get some of them to be .dlls, but not all of them, partly because the updating of the packages stops when it fails to find Fabrik. But I am also having this other problem which may or may not be more pressing than this, this other problem being the only error I get when I try to build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856314/monodevelop-error-executing-task-csc-argument-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-p

Comment: The first screenshot looks fine to me. On my Mac in the `From Packages` I see the packages without any .dll at the end. The screenshot in my answer is taken from Windows so what is displayed is slightly different. If the .dlls were missing then they would show up in red in the Solution window.

Comment: thanks! I guess I just have the one problem then, for now at leas.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. References aren't getting added when I add a new package.  I have to manually add references to the downloaded DLLs, one by one.

Comment: If this is repeatable then would you be able to file a bug with steps to reproduce the problem on bugzilla? https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is a little unclear as to what specific problem he/she having.   I'm guessing (since they were using entity framework) that they are somewhat experienced and has used packages before.

Had similiar and maybe same problem where it will report missing assemblies ('are you missing an assembly reference or using statement?' error), even when the correct assemblies are successfully loaded as packages.

In this case I believe it may have happened because the location of the solution file was moved in the repo, which screwed with the package restore paths.    You can confirm this by looking at verbose debug logs in monodevelop or msbuild/.net core.

Or you can just delete the packages and re-add them, which is probably the fastest way.

It should be noted that matt_ward's post and screenshot above is what the "refences from packages" looks like visually in the IDE in normal/good situation.

Relative to this good situation- in my case when this stopped working, I had the packages in the packages part... but no "references from packages" section.

Delete and re-add packages or double-check paths in packages.config (located in same directory as the project file in question).  Works again.