# Monodevelop Error executing task Csc: Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: pathToTool

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, monodevelop

I'm having a couple problems loading a .NET MVC 4 project I was working on in VS in Monodevelop. My (other problem)[[Unable to Add NuGet Packages to References in Monodevelop 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854290/unable-to-add-nuget-packages-to-references-in-monodevelop-5]) is related to packages, and this one is related to what I believe is the C# compiler?

The error in the title is the only error I am getting when I try to build the solution. Any help would be much appreciated, and please let me know what other information I should provide.

Thanks!